# Is 'water' an appropriate tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I had the thought that [water](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water) is a relevant tag, given tremendous range of water mechanics, and the people that that focus on water research for that reason.

Also, many participants here may be those working in, or interested in, the water purification industry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's a fine tag. I have approved the edit creating it, in fact :)

The only downside I can see to it is that it could be misused and applied to all questions about aqueous solutions or reactions in water.

Comment: This seems like an appropriate answer to accept, but I welcome thoughts and feedback from others.

Comment: @NewAlexandria I'm 100% in agreement, I think it's an important concept in environmental chemistry.