# Separate water and water-treatment tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Is a [water-treatment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-treatment) tag appropriate?

There is a tag for [water](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water) discussed previously on the chemistry SE.  [Is 'water' an appropriate tag?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/is-water-an-appropriate-tag)

[water-treatment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-treatment) is different in that it excludes all of the chemical phenomena which describes water's behavior and narrows specifically to techniques used to treat either drinking water or wastewater.

Comment: I am not sure why, but I do not like using the environmental-chemistry tag for water-treatment questions.

Comment: There has been a recent discussion about the use of the environmental-chemistry and the  green-chemistry tags.  But honestly Im not sure theres sufficient demand for a separate tag for water-treatment...

Comment: Id also point out that by re-tagging all of these posts with water-treatment you're filling the homepage with very old questions. . . Perhaps better to do this at a time when the site is relatively inactive.

Comment: I am not a big fan of this, but since it has already been done, I guess it does no harm keeping it. From my point of view, [tag:water-treatment] falls very much within the scope of [tag:purification]. || For future reference, if you want a discussion about a tag you might want to wait about two weeks, not everybody checks meta every day. (At the time of writing it was viewed only 25 times.) Otherwise just might want to skip it altogether, because discussing something after the fact does not make any sense any more.

Comment: [purification] is a major part of [water-treatment]; however, not all water treatment topics fall under [purification].  Examples which would fall under water-treatment, but not purification are: (1) disinfection - which is aimed at reducing pathogens -  (2) land application - which is aimed at disposing of water.   (3) pH / alkalinity adjustments.  -- After looking I was surprised at the number of water treatment questions, or questions deriving from misunderstandings of water treatment fundamentals.  I am trying to be courteous by limiting the number of new tags.

Comment: Somebody do a MATT of [tag:water-treatment]

Comment: @Jan 12-15, depending on how optimistic you look at it. My answer is like Mart's. "Meh". If it creates problems in the future, we'd get rid of it; but it doesn't seem to be of the problematic type.